# XML RPC connection using PHP

Tags: php, xml, rpc

Has anyone ever created code to connect to Adestra.com's XML RPC API with PHP.

I have seen a couple of XML RPC examples on here, but none of them demonstrate how to send username and password authentication via headers.  According to the Adestra Support:-

"We use HTTP basic authentication, which requires the username and password passed through as headers. Most XML-RPC clients will handle this for you by exposing a more convenient interface for supplying credentials. To ensure credentials are passed securely, please connect to the API over https (https://app.adestra.com/api/xmlrpc)."

I [think I] understand the basic process here, i.e. you use an XML RPC library to encode function calls and parameters into XML format, and get a reponse from the server, but how would you send the authentication?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to download XMLRPC client library. This library is used to create an XMLRPC object which will communicate with ADESTRA API services.

Bellow is example of calling API *contact.search* method. The principle stays the same for other API methods:

```
//******* LOGIN DATA*******/
$account = 'account';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$adestraCoreTable=1;


/**INITIALIZE API*****/
require_once('xmlrpc.inc');//First inlcude XMLRPC client library


//Calling Adestra API with our credentials
$xmlrpc= new xmlrpc_client("http://$account.$username:$password@new.adestra.com/api/xmlrpc");
$xmlrpc->setDebug(0);
$xmlrpc->request_charset_encoding="UTF-8";


$msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
                    "contact.search",
                    array(
                        //Set user id
                        new xmlrpcval($adestraCoreTable, "int"),
                        new xmlrpcval(
                            array(
                                "email"=> new xmlrpcval("test@test.com", "string"),
                            ),"struct"
                        )
                    )

                );
$response = $xmlrpc->send($msg);//Send request, and get the response


if($response->faultCode()){//API call not succeed. This can happen when there is no connection
    $errorMessage=htmlspecialchars($response->faultString());
    $errorCode=htmlspecialchars($response->faultCode());
}

$returnValue = php_xmlrpc_decode($response->value());//Parse API return
if(empty($returnValue)){//If return value is empty, user not find in Adestra, we should log that
    $errorMessage="Searching user by mail did not succeed! Problably there is no this user in Adestra DB";
    continue;///SCRIPT MUST continue for other users
}
$adestraUSERID=$returnValue[0]["id"];//Use this ID for what ever you want
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd like to know if that comma `,` after the ` "email"` key=>val in the above array is intentional or a typo? Maybe that was creating some problems during execution.

Comment: Optiobally, you can remove the comma, but it will not cause any errors

Comment: By the "XMLRPC client library", do you mean this: http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/

Comment: Hi @EfficionDave, I'm not 100% sure (this was 5 years ago), but I think it is the library you linked.